# tabulate total usage by month in a year

Tags: calculated-columns

i would like to list the total consumption used by month for a customer table

```
 Date              Reading
-------          ----------
02-dec-11         750
03-jan-12         1000
05-feb-12         1250
  .
  .
  .
05-dec-12         2300
```

Expected results

```
Month               Total 
-------           ---------
JAN                 250 (1000-750)
FEB                 250 (1250-1000)
  .
  .
```

.